# Using 'Object' functions in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

I want to be able to have 'objects' with certain functions that refer to themselves (I have no idea what to call this) in Lua. I have seen code of what I'm trying to do but I have never understood what any of it actually means. I have tried looking over the Lua website but no luck.

Basic Code:

```
table = {}

function newTable(...)
  ...
  return setmetatable(table)
end

function table:funcName(...)
  ...
end
```

Can someone explain what is going on here and how I can use this please? Thanks for reading!

Comment: I recommend checking out the [Object Orientation chapter](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) from in the Programming in Lua book. It explains everything you want starting from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

missingno already mentioned one resource that explains how this works. You can also check out [**lua wiki's OOP**](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming) section for more explanation and examples.

To summary briefly your example, starting with how to use it. Note, I changed some of the names so it doesn't affect the standard modules that comes with lua. You create a new object by calling `newObject`. You can invoke that object's methods using `:` followed by the method name:

```
-- create two instances
object1 = newObject()
object2 = newObject()

-- call 'my_function' method for object1
object1:my_function()
```

You'll need to know a bit about metatables to understand how this machinery works behind the scenes. When you perform a call like:

```
object1:my_function()
```

That is just syntax sugar for:

```
object1.my_function(object1)
```

This can be broken down further into:

```
object1["my_function"](object1)
```

Now `object1` is just an empty table returned by `newObject` -- it doesn't have a `"my_function"` key. Normally this would result in an error because you're trying to call a `nil` value. However, you can change this behavior using metatables. The basic idea is to setup the `__index` metamethod to point to a table that holds your class methods:

```
object_table = {}
object_table.__index = object_table
function newObject(...)
  return setmetatable({}, object_table)
end
```

The method lookup process will then look like this: `object1` -> `table`. If `object1` doesn't have a key, `table` is consulted next. If `table` has that key the associated value is returned. If `table` doesn't have it either then `nil` is returned since `table` doesn't have a metatable.

With this setup you can "override" a method for a particular object instance by just assigning the method name and function as key-value pair for that object.

```
object2.my_function = function (...)
  -- do something different
end
```

Comment: Your post is good but it can be misleading because you used the Lua keyword `function` as a method/function name and table key, and this won't work. I suggest to change it to something like `my_function` or an equivalently readable name.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati good point, was getting lazy with the explanation.

Comment: I noticed that now, you also overwrite the standard `table` library doing `table={}`, maybe a safer `meta_table={}` is better :-)

Comment: I checked out the OOP programming section, and it has helped me so much! thanks man! Your tutorial too made a good outline before i read the webpage.